# как конвертиравать string в numeric

Tags: javascript

пример я получил данные - "34" нужно провести с ним математические операции

Comment: Сколько ж уже можно...

Comment: @Cheg почему `Разница ParseInt, ParseFloat и Number` когда дубль все же первый?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский предыдущий вопрос же как раз и был закрыт со ссылкой на "Разница..."

Comment: @Cheg и почему ты думаешь, что он отвечает на вопрос "Как сделать numeric из string?" Он отвечает совсем на другой вопрос... причем понятно из названия вопроса) Так что это явная ошибка

Answer (score 0):

допиши унарный оператор + перед переменной с текстом,
`var a = '34';
alert( +a );`

Он преобразует строку к числу